# Count number of cells with color fill Excel 2013

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2013

Is there a way/a function to count the number of color filled cells in Excel 2013 without using VBA? Something like

```
COUNTxxx(A1:A20)
```

Comment: As far as I know, and what I have recently googled: no. But you can make a custom function with vba that you use like a normal excel fomula.

Comment: Agree with Andreas. I think the best (and to my knowledge the only) way is to write a custom function in VBA. The alternative would be to add a helper column where you put a 1 if the same condition is met which puts in the color, and a zero in all other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to use [VBA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2815384)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to fulfill this task using only the Excel built-in function(s).

There are 2 ways:

1. Create one or several User Defined Functions using VBA that will count / sum colored cells and then call them from the workbook. You can also place these UDFs into the personal.xlsb file, then you don't need to copy them each time in a new workbook. 
   However, it is not possible to correctly process cells colored with a conditional format using UDF.
2. Use a special add-in that will count / sum the necessary cells based on their color.

You can find more details about the ways to count / sum colored cells, including 
the VBA code, in this blog post:
[How to count and sum cells by color in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/12/count-sum-by-color-excel/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Function CountColor(xRange As Range, xColor As Long) As Long
Dim xCell As Range
For Each xCell In xRange
    If xCell.Font.ColorIndex = xColor Then
        CountColor = CountColor + 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Use this function in excel

```
=CountColor(A1:E25;3)
```

3 = Red